# FB.ui not working on IE

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer, block, externalinterface

I need help desesperately, it's been a week since I'm stuck trying to resolve this problem, I call FB.ui in FireFox and Chrome without any problem, but when I try with IE it doesn't appear the Facebook dialog. Actually the code is like this:

```
function inviteFriends(myMessage) {
    var obj = {
        method: 'apprequests',
        message: myMessage,
        icon: 'http://www.mywebsite.com/logo.jpg',
        data: 'tracking information for the user'
    };

    FB.ui(obj, callbackInvite);
}

var callbackInvite = function(response) {
        document["flashContent"].InvitedFriends(response);
}
```

Please, any help will be welcomed

Comment: Do any errors appear in the console?

Comment: Where you able to fix this? I have the same problem. The facebook dialog is not shown and no message on the console.

Answer (score 2):

Might try this out:

displayMode = "popup";

Looks like there's a bug with IE and FB.ui

http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=17565